# In jmeter how can i run transaction controller by putting multiple http request in it?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

i need your help for transaction controller in jmeter.

- I have a requirement to run 4 http request as one flow , so i have put them in one transaction controller , but once i run the script then all 4 requests runs individual and after that it runs in a transaction controller.

My expectation is that a script should run all 4 request in a transaction controller as one flow.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to fully understand [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) concept.

It doesn't really get "executed", it is only a sum of its children elapsed times.

If you add i.e. [View Results in Table](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_in_Table) listener you will see that:

1. Requests are being executed as "one flow", one by one
2. Transaction Controller response time is the sum of its children response times

   [image]

Check out [What is JMeter’s Transaction Controller?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/JMeter-Transaction-controller-behavior/) article for more details if needed

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement correctly, you can use below option to get your answer,
Select "Transaction controller" -> check on "Create Parent Sample"
[image]